# What is the most efficient type of software bandpass filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design, software-implementation, bandpass, c

I'm writing a C++ application to extract four modulated carrier signals at four separate frequencies, from a single input signal. I've designed four FIR filters at [t-filter.appspot.com](http://t-filter.appspot.com) but they run very slowly, even when I reduce # of taps to 80.

Is there a better option? People seem to point to biquad filters – are these different from FIR filters, and do they run more quickly in software?

Comment: Have you considered doing this in the frequency domain ?

Comment: One biquad runs a lot faster than a FIR filter with 80 taps. A biquad filter has 5 coefficients, so it requires only 5 multiplications per sample. Your FIR filter requires 80 multiplications per sample (because it is linear phase it only requires 40 multiplications).

Comment: Paul R is right; this application could be a good candidate for frequency-domain filtering, for instance using the [overlap-save](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) technique.

Comment: @niaren is right.  A biquad is very fast and [much less complicated than taking FFTs and worrying about edge effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929401/dsp-filtering-in-the-frequency-domain-via-fft).  See http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/ for an online design tool (very simple text interface, no graphing like t-filter.)  You might try the "Chebyshev" or "resonator" options.

Comment: Discrete wavelet transforms could maybe help you. They are definitely fast enough anyway, but it will depend on how easy you can get the frequency and band-width to fit.

Answer (score 4):

Frequency domain filtering (FFT), as suggested by some comments, is definitely wrong -- it's even slower, or same speed at best! A recursive filter (IIR) is the fastes possible solution. If you choose a typical second order filter (called biquad in engineering slang) of Butterworth type and do your math right (factoring out coefficients) you only have 3 multiplications and five addition.

---

Edit: link to classics page: [filter cookbook](https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/_downloads/3e1dc886e7849251d6747b194d482272/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt)

Comment: Whether an FFT filter is slower or faster depends on the number of filter taps.

Comment: Yes sure, but your fft must have a window width of about as many samples as your filter has taps in order to get a simliar frequency resolution. But your fft is O(N log N) at best and you have to do two of them vs one O(N) fir filter.

Comment: Convolutions are O(NM), where M is the length of the filter.

Comment: For a butterworth type filter you can even do it with two multiplications per sample if you're not constrained to a direct-form. Anyway, I also agree that the FFT seems a little overkill unless additional analysis or processing takes place...

Comment: Interesting answer! I was just getting a handle on how FIR filters worked, but I guess I'll have to dig even deeper and try to figure out IIR. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that IIR / biquad filters have variable impulse responses (hence the name I guess). My first thought is that such a filter would not work, because I need to synchronize the timing of the 4 data streams on those 4 carrier frequencies, ideally down to the exact sample. Would a second order IIR filter insert random delay into my signal? Hopefully I am misinterpreting what impulse response means.